# easier way to get mouse movenment on window control IN WINDOW LOOP than subclassing

Tags: c++, winapi, mouseevent, mouse

First of all, yes I have read the other articles deal (I like your "similar question title"-window ), I am just curious if there are better ways of doing that.

**Problem:** When using effects or anythings else that involes tracking, WinAPI appearantly decided that **buttons, edits and maybe all other Common Controls do not pass WM_MOUSEMOVE to their parent handle**. This comes unhandy, when the user - for example - stays (actually moves) too long on a button and the **event is unintentionally triggered**.

Initial Question: How to solve that ?

**Answer 1**: Subclassing. Quite handy and safe but needs also some time so skip that for now.

**Answer 2:** TrackMouseEvent + "if-conditioning" --> may be slow and surely gets very complex.

**NoGo:** Using notify flags as BS_NOTIFY for buttons do not work because they take care about mouse clicks and focus.

**QUESTION:** Any other ideas? Did Windows 7  "secretly" introduce a flag for that or does some pro-grammer know a trick to deal with it easier?

NOTE: I do not want to annoy somebody. I just want to ask before adding unnecessarly much code.

Comment: This question rambles pretty badly.  I'm guessing SetCapture() is the solution but it is hard to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Subclassing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#subclassing_v6) is by far your simplest option. If you are looking for a easier option, you won't find one. As shown by the link, with a very minimal amount of code you can already solve your problem. If you wish to have the functionality such that the parent handle does pass the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message up the window hierarchy, simply subclass it, then when handling that message forward the parameters onto the parent.

I'm slightly unclear however, about what you mean by:

> for example - stays (actually moves) too long on a button and the **event is unintentionally triggered**.

For example:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK ButtonProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam,
                               LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        SendMessage((HWND)dwRefData, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

This is assuming that you passed in the parent `HWND` under `dwRefData`.